# How to remove leading zeros from the Array of Numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, leading-zero

```
 let array = [000232, 0043, 0000454523, 0234]
```

Expected output: `[232, 43, 454523, 234]`

There are lots of ways, where we can remove leading zeros if it is a string or arrays of strings.

```
arr.map( (value) => { console.log(parseInt(value, 10) )})
```

So, what I tried, to convert those Array of numbers to string values:

```
1. array.map(String);
2. array.join().split(',');
```

But it's not working as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Numbers don't have _leading zeros_ o.O

Comment: Totally right, @Andreas 
Real scenario here is likely:
let array = ["000232", "0043", "0000454523", "0234"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With leding zero, you use [octal numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Octal_numbers). To get decimals, you need to convert back to octals and parse this values as decimal numbers.

This approach works only on an array of octal numbers. It is not possible, to check if a value is taken from an octal literal.

```js
let array = [000232, 0043, 0000454523, 0234],
    values = array.map(n => parseInt(n.toString(8), 10));

console.log(values);
```

Comment: check the expected output

Comment: It still print the octal values! Use: `array.map(n => parseInt(n.toString(8)));`

Comment: why it's print `154,
  35,
  153939,
  156`??

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
  let tmpArray = [000232, 0043, 0000454523, 0234];
  let row1 = tmpArray.map(function (val) {
    return Number(val.toString(8));
  });
  console.log(row1);
```